# WiFi N7260: Direct firmware load failed with error -2

Tags: wireless, firmware, dell-vostro, iwlwifi

Dell laptop. Wifi not working after installing ubuntu 14.04. Tried to update firmware, but not working. Any ideas?

/var/log/syslog:

```
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.370168] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux, in-tree:
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.370171] Copyright(c) 2003-2013 Intel Corporation
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.370312] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: irq 65 for MSI/MSI-X
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.370555] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.370557] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Falling back to user helper
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.372460] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.1.7.0 op_mode iwlmvm
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.377572] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wireless N 7260, REV=0xFFFFFFFF
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.377619] iwlwifi 0000:08:00.0: L1 Disabled; Enabling L0S
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395299] ------------[ cut here ]------------
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395310] WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 13295 at /build/buildd/linux-3.13.0/drivers/net/wireless/iwlwifi/pcie/trans.c:1002 iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0xcb/0xe0 [iwlwifi]()
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395311] Timeout waiting for hardware access (CSR_GP_CNTRL 0xffffffff)
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395312] Modules linked in: iwlmvm(+) iwlwifi ctr ccm rtl8192cu rtl_usb rtlwifi rtl8192c_common arc4 dell_wmi sparse_keymap dell_laptop intel_rapl x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp dcdbas rtl8187 coretemp snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek mac80211 snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec kvm_intel uvcvideo snd_hwdep kvm videobuf2_vmalloc videobuf2_memops snd_pcm videobuf2_core snd_page_alloc cfg80211 eeprom_93cx6 serio_raw snd_seq_midi videodev joydev snd_seq_midi_event rtsx_pci_ms snd_rawmidi rfcomm lpc_ich snd_seq bnep memstick mei_me btusb snd_seq_device snd_timer bluetooth snd mei soundcore intel_smartconnect binfmt_misc parport_pc nls_iso8859_1 ppdev lp mac_hid parport dm_crypt hid_generic usbhid hid rtsx_pci_sdmmc crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel aes_x86_64 nouveau lrw gf128mul glue_helper ablk_helper cryptd i915 psmouse mxm_wmi ttm ahci libahci i2c_algo_bit r8169 drm_kms_helper rtsx_pci mii drm wmi video [last unloaded: iwlwifi]
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395367] CPU: 3 PID: 13295 Comm: modprobe Tainted: G        W    3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395368] Hardware name: Dell Inc. Vostro 5470/0G5M5F, BIOS A05 12/06/2013
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395370]  0000000000000009 ffff8800b9839af8 ffffffff8171bcb4 ffff8800b9839b40
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395372]  ffff8800b9839b30 ffffffff810676cd ffff88022f5c8000 ffff88022f5cb258
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395374]  ffff8800b9839bd0 0000000000000000 ffff88022d03d7c0 ffff8800b9839b90
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395377] Call Trace:
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395383]  [] dump_stack+0x45/0x56
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395386]  [] warn_slowpath_common+0x7d/0xa0
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395388]  [] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x4c/0x50
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395393]  [] ? iwl_read32+0x1a/0x80 [iwlwifi]
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395397]  [] iwl_trans_pcie_grab_nic_access+0xcb/0xe0 [iwlwifi]
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395400]  [] iwl_read_prph+0x2b/0xb0 [iwlwifi]
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395404]  [] iwl_pcie_apm_init+0x20d/0x280 [iwlwifi]
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395408]  [] iwl_trans_pcie_start_hw+0x55/0x1b0 [iwlwifi]
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395415]  [] iwl_op_mode_mvm_start+0x43a/0x570 [iwlmvm]
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395419]  [] _iwl_op_mode_start.isra.2+0x4a/0xb0 [iwlwifi]
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395423]  [] iwl_opmode_register+0xc1/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395426]  [] ? 0xffffffffa0743fff
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395431]  [] iwl_mvm_init+0x37/0x1000 [iwlmvm]
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395434]  [] do_one_initcall+0xfa/0x1b0
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395438]  [] ? set_memory_nx+0x43/0x50
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395442]  [] load_module+0x12dd/0x1b40
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395445]  [] ? store_uevent+0x40/0x40
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395448]  [] SyS_finit_module+0x86/0xb0
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395451]  [] tracesys+0xe1/0xe6
Jul 21 15:30:21 rwilco-Vostro-5470 kernel: [ 2631.395453] ---[ end trace 4add81c2b58868d0 ]---
```

Comment: Do you have the latest firmware? sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade

Comment: Yes, I've tried this. I also tried to update firmware manualy by downloading to /lib/firmware iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode file