# BT functionality gone

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, hardware

**THE issue:**
The bluetooth hardware device has didn't find/turn on/connect to some other external and paired/added devices.

**Symptoms:**
The command `$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service` Shows:

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-02-12 12:38:25 -03; 11min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 1325 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 8123)
     Memory: 1.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─1325 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

feb 12 12:38:25 systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
feb 12 12:38:25 bluetoothd[1325]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
feb 12 12:38:25 systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
feb 12 12:38:25 bluetoothd[1325]: Starting SDP server
feb 12 12:38:25 bluetoothd[1325]: Bluetooth management interface 1.20 initialized
```

The command `$ rfkill list` Shows:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
```

The command `$ dmesg | grep bluetooth` shows:

```
[13.253973] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for rtl_bt/rtl8723b_config.bin failed with error -2
```

**Sources asked:**
[Source 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/500612/wifi-n7260-direct-firmware-load-failed-with-error-2)
[Source 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1308862/bluetooth-device-suddenly-gone)
[Source 3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/688090/cannot-unblock-soft-blocked-bluetooth)
[Source 4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/940075/error-on-wake-up-hci0-failed-to-load-rtl-bt-rtl8723b-config-bin)

None of then solve the issue.
Any ideas?

**Workaround:**
The issue was solved after hard restart from suspend/sleep (black screen) mode.