# Bluetooth is not working on HP 15, Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, hp, realtek, realtek-wireless

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, My Bluetooth was working fine on Windows before, but I shifted completely to Ubuntu, and now I cant use my Bluetooth. I am new to Linux, any help in this regard will be appreciated! My hardware: **RTL8821CE**
I have attached screenshots.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjHzw.png)

```
$ lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0408:5362 Quanta Computer, Inc. HP TrueVision HD Camera
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
[    0.090350] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    3.675860] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[    6.074755] audit: type=1400 audit(1644766913.890:76): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.obex" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=936 comm="obexd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[    6.101004] audit: type=1400 audit(1644766913.910:77): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=933 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
[    6.150073] audit: type=1400 audit(1644766913.958:78): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=933 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[    6.354094] audit: type=1400 audit(1644766914.166:79): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=1224 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
[    6.355022] audit: type=1400 audit(1644766914.166:80): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=1224 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[    6.369999] audit: type=1400 audit(1644766914.182:81): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.obex" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=1228 comm="obexd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[    6.534596] audit: type=1400 audit(1644766914.350:82): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=1342 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
[    6.535209] audit: type=1400 audit(1644766914.350:83): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=1342 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
[    6.546348] audit: type=1400 audit(1644766914.358:84): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.obex" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=1343 comm="obexd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
```

```
$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor pre>
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-02-14 18:51:51 PKT; 2h 27min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 38553 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9313)
     Memory: 1.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─38553 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

فروری 14 18:51:51 HP-Notebook systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
فروری 14 18:51:51 HP-Notebook bluetoothd[38553]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
فروری 14 18:51:51 HP-Notebook systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
فروری 14 18:51:51 HP-Notebook bluetoothd[38553]: Starting SDP server
فروری 14 18:51:51 HP-Notebook bluetoothd[38553]: Bluetooth management interface>

$ rfkill list 
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ dmesg | grep bluetooth
```

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, Could you provide/attach to your question the commands listed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1392541/bt-functionality-gone) ?

Answer (score 1):

Open Additional Drivers, select & apply `rtl8821ce-dkms`, reboot.

Or, alternatively, install it manually:

```
sudo apt install rtl8821ce-dkms
```

Comment: installed it, WiFi started working, but Bluetooth is still not working.